# How to make a check constraint which references two columns?

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

I want to create a table Sp in Oracle with following query :

```
create table SP(Order_date date ,Dely_date date  check(Dely_date>Order_date));
```

But the problem is that oracle shows an error "Column check constraint cannot reference other columns"

But if I create this table without this condition `check(Dely_date>Order_date)`
then table is created.

Tell me why check constraint can't work with two columns.

If I alter the SP table with this clause  `check(Dely_date>Order_date)`
then my check constraint works properly.
But at the time of creation check constraint can't work with above condition.

Comment: Why are there MySQL, Visual Studio and XAMPP tags?

Comment: I really don't kno

Answer (score 3):

That's how Oracle did it - inline check constraint can't reference another column.

Workaround? Create out-of-line constraint:

```
SQL> create table SP
  2    (Order_date date ,
  3     Dely_date  date,
  4     --
  5     constraint ch_date check (Dely_date > Order_date)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>   insert into sp values (date '2020-03-03', date '2020-02-15');
  insert into sp values (date '2020-03-03', date '2020-02-15')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_DATE) violated


SQL>   insert into sp values (date '2020-03-03', date '2020-04-23');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first attempt you are trying to create an **inline** constraint. We are only allowed to reference the owning column in an inline constraint. Your ALTER TABLE statement succeeds because it creates a **table level** constraint, and table level constraints can reference more than one column.

This gives us the clue how to fix your code so you can create the check constraint in the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
create table SP(Order_date date
               ,Dely_date  date 
               ,constraint dates_ck check(Dely_date > Order_date)
);
```

Note the comma before the `constraint` keyword: this makes it a table level (out-of-line) constraint. Also, note that I have named the constraint `dates_ck`. It's always good practice to name constraints, but in this case it's mandatory: we cannot create an out-of-line check constraint without naming it. (Try it and it'll hurl the same ORA-02438 exception.)

Comment: What is dates_ck after constraint

Comment: @ShahzuKhan - turned my response from comment into part of question.

Comment: I have create table without constraint's name and it is working properly in oracle

Comment: @ShahzuKhan - if you think my explanation is wrong or incomplete please post the statement you say works so I can update my answer for you.